# Mocha / Chai testing: How can I make it more strict?

Tags: reactjs, testing, npm, mocha.js, chai

Using Mocha and Chai, I have notice many unreliable tests. I would like these ALL to fail. Similar StackOverflow questions are because of Async and not using done(). Even if this was my case, I would surely want it to fail!

I have a typo in what should be `exist`. It doesnt tell me this unless I make a type in a particular position.

1. Why do this test not fail?
2. Is there something I am doing wrong?
3. How can I make Mocha / Chai more strict?

#### These all pass!?

```
expect(component.find('textarea')).to.exest;
expect(component.find('textarea')).to.not.exest;
expect(component.find('textarea')).to.exsdafdsafdsfdsafest;
```

#### This doesnt.

```
expect(component.find('textarea')).BLAHASDF.exest;
```

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'exest' of undefined`

Well, thank you Chai for telling me now!

Ok I am being a bit silly, but I can assure you this frustrate me a lot!

Is there some settings, or is there something I am missing, or is there another library that trumps this one?

Comment: You _could_ assert your assertions: `expect(expect(component.find('textarea')).to.exest).to.exist`

Comment: @robertklep ha, and what if you do `expect(expect(component.find('textarea')).to.exest).to.exest` ? I guess you could assert the assertion for the assertion too ? :D

Comment: @fabio.sussetto someone should invent a recursive assertion interface ;) FWIW, a non-existent property would be `undefined`, which is something you could test for. But a function-based interface may be better suitable if you need to make sure you didn't make typos :)

Comment: @robertklep, thats great man. lol

Answer (score 2):

What are you describing is the "normal" javascript behaviour when you try to access undefined properties. It's not something related to Chai, Mocha or any other library.

In Javascript, trying to access an undefined properties of an object doesn't cause any errors. You can do for example

```
var a = { foo: 'bar'};
console.log(a.baz);  // This logs undefined, doesn't cause any error.
```

So when you do `expect(component.find('textarea')).BLAHASDF.exest;` that instead will throw an error because you first try to access `BLAHASDF`, which evaluates to `undefined` and then you try to do `undefined.exest`, which will raise an error because `undefined` is a primitive, not an object.

I agree with you though that Chai Expect/Should APIs for these cases are not ideal. I'd prefer to do something like `expect(component.find('textarea')).exist()` so that a typo there (e.g. .exests()) would indeed cause an error ("Undefined is not a function").

As noted in the comments though, you can indeed use different assertion styles in Chai: http://chaijs.com/api/assert/

If you look for another alternative library in this regard, I'd recommend either Jest https://facebook.github.io/jest/)
or the minimalistic Tapejs (https://github.com/substack/tape)

Comment: This isn't related to Mocha, which is assertion-library-agnostic. You could replace Chai with [`expect`](https://github.com/mjackson/expect) if you prefer functions instead of properties.

Comment: @robertklep you're right, I was going to check if you could swap the assertion library as I did remember something like that.

Comment: robertklep, chai.expect? This is what I am using. Is there another assertion library?

Comment: Thanks @robertklep  ,  I edited my answer to make it clear you can use different assertion styles in Chai

Comment: @MichaelBruce Chai offers one implementation of `expect`, but there are plenty of other assertion libraries. The one I linked to has different call semantics, that may suit you better. See [this search result](https://npms.io/search?q=assertion) for more alternatives.

Comment: @robertklep I am confused from you saying `You could replace Chai with expect`. Is this not what I have done? Yes, I am actively checking out these assertion libraries. I would prefer a function based call as well.

Comment: @MichaelBruce you're using `require('chai').expect`, so you're using Chai (to be specific, you're using its implementation of an Except-like testing interface). There is also a completely unrelated package, called `expect`, that implements something similar, just a _bit_ different (and probably more to your liking).